# Python plot drop lines with repeating value in column

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot

I have a .txt file like this

```
episode:2840  score:6.0  memory length:700345  epsilon:0.5576491831247304   steps:359    recent reward:5.95
episode:2841  score:4.0  memory length:700629  epsilon:0.5574965123606621   steps:284    recent reward:5.96
episode:2842  score:5.0  memory length:700911  epsilon:0.5573449596383373   steps:282    recent reward:5.93
Max lifes :5
episode:2800  score:7.0  memory length:687331  epsilon:0.5646918805492361   steps:268    recent reward:6.04
episode:2801  score:5.0  memory length:687678  epsilon:0.5645029051613243   steps:347    recent reward:6.03
episode:2802  score:6.0  memory length:688027  epsilon:0.564312906709082   steps:349    recent reward:6.03
```

Starting from `episode:0` and updating, but every now and then I see this `Max lifes :5` line and then some of the episodes repeat. I want to remove the lines that I see an episode reappearing. How can I do this? The problem is that only the `episode` number is repeating, not the rest of the columns. So for `episode:2800` we get different score, epsilon etc the second time it appears. This is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import islice


def next_1000_lines(file_opened, N):
    return [x.strip() for x in islice(file_opened, N)]



with open("ouput_10000.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    x, y = [], []

    for line in lines:

        if line[:3] != "Max":
            x.append(line.split()[0])
            y.append(line.split()[7])
            x = next_1000_lines(x, 1000)
            y = next_1000_lines(y, 1000)

f.close()

print(x, y)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I want to create a plot of the `reward` for every 1000 `episodes`, is this `next_1000_lines` function correct? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `next_1000_lines` method is just doing a `strip` on the contents of `x` and `y` up to 1000 elements, and you are calling it on every line. Why not just to the strip as you go, once per line:

```
line_count = 0
for line in lines:

    if line[:3] != "Max":
        tokens = line.split()
        episode = int(tokens[0].split(':')[1])
        if episode not in x:
            reward = float(tokens[7].split(':')[1])
            x.append(episode)
            y.append(reward)
            line_count += 1
    if line_count == 1000:
        linePlot = plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()
        linePlot[0].figure.savefig(fileName)
        line_count = 0
        x = []
        y = []
```

Haven't actually run this code, so there may be errors.

Comment: It indeed removes the lines where the episode is repeated, thanks! I would like to create a plot of how the reward changes, for every 1000 episodes, and I thought that maybe this `next_1000_lines` function could do that. Do you know what's the best approach to make a plot for every 1000 lines?

Comment: Added code to count the lines and do the plot when 1000 lines is reached. You will need to add code to plot any lines read at the end that don't reach 1000.

Comment: Thanks!! Btw do you know any quick fix on how to save each different plot as an image?

Comment: Added code to save the plot. Note again that I haven't actually run this code. You will need to replace `fileName` with a unique file name for each plot.

Answer (score 0):

I divided the problem into parts. Every episode/reward data point is saved to the lists unless the episode number is lower than the one before. Now, you should be able to inspect the `episodes` and `rewards` list, before plotting it. Afterwards a new plot is created for elements 0..999, 1000..1999 and so on.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read lines from file
filename = "ouput_10000.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Extract episode/reward data points
episodes = []
rewards = []
for line in lines:
    if not line.startswith("episode"):
        # Not a line with episode/reward data
        continue
    columns = line.split()
    try:
        episode = int(columns[0].split(":")[1])
        reward = float(columns[7].split(":")[1])
    except:
        # Not a number
        continue
    if episode in episodes:
        # We don't want duplicate episodes
        continue
    episodes.append(episode)
    rewards.append(reward)

# Plot data
N = 1000
for i in range(int((len(episodes)-1)/N)+1):
    plt.plot(episodes[i*N:i*N+N], rewards[i*N:i*N+N])
    plt.savefig("plot{}.png".format(i))
    plt.close()
```